# php.ini include_path not working

Tags: php

I have changed "php.ini" to set include_path variable value as follows:
`include_path = ".:/var/www/Projects/sunpath/www/_library`"

but i have written `require_once 'setup.inc.php`' in the file `abc.php` which is in the path "`/var/www/Projects/sunpath/www/abc.php`" but while i am trying to access from browser using the path "`http://hostname/Projects/sunpath/www/abc.php`"

include_path works for abc.php but not for all the files in the project. what else i need to do.
please help me.

Comment: Where is `setup.inc.php` located? Where are the other files located that do not work?

Answer (score 0):

```
$GLOBALS['CODE_ROOT'] = dirname(__FILE__);
require_once $GLOBALS['CODE_ROOT'] . '/setup.inc.php';
```

Try putting this in your abc.php providing that setup.inc.php is in the same directory.